# Show that $A$ has measure $0$.

Tags: measure-theory

I am new to *Measure theory*, and I wanted to solve the following exercise:

*Show that the following set has measure $0$*:

$A = \{(\frac{1}{n},y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: n \in \mathbb{N}, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

**Definition of measure:** $$|A|^* = inf \left\{\sum_{I \in \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{v}(I): \mathcal{C} \textrm{ is a collection of open intervals that covers $A$} \right\},$$
where $v(I)$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional interval $I$, defined as usual.

Let us prove that every segment of $\mathbb{R}$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

Let $I = (a,b) \times \{q\}$ be a segment.

Let $C_{\delta} = (a,b) \times (q-\delta,q+\delta)$ with $\delta > 0$. It is clear that $C_\delta$ is an open interval that covers $I$. Therefore, its measure is equal to its volume, that is, $v(C_\delta) = (b-a)(q+\delta-q+\delta) = (b-a)2\delta$. 
We can make $\delta$ arbitrarily small, then $v(C_\delta) = |C_\delta|^* = 0$.

Now, getting back to $A$:

We can see $A$ as the union of vertical segments that pass through $\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$, that is:

$$A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\} \times \mathbb{R}.$$
As we know that segments have measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we get that $|A|^* = 0$.

Comment: The above is correct but is missing a step. You have shown that a finite interval has measure zero. You should show that the infinite interval has measure zero.

Comment: A small quibble: I understand what you really meant by it, but no matter how small $\delta$ is, $v(C_\delta) > 0$. It is only the limit as $\delta \to 0$ that is $0$. And of course, copper hat is correct. $A$ is a union of full lines, not finite segments.